# clear all select2 options

Tags: jquery-select2, select-options

I can't find on select2 documentation a way to remove all the options in a select2 form.
The old stckoverflow answers to this questions seem not to work since the new version (I'm using 4.0.3) has a different behavior

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just

`$('#id').empty().trigger("change");`

Where '#id' is the jQuery selector for your select2 element.

Comment: Sorry, I sent it without finishing the last sentence. Is it ok now?

Comment: Sorry … don't seems to work on 4.1.0-RC1 maybe an RC issue

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer will delete all values, but in the official documentation it says:

`$("#id").val(null).trigger("change");`

Comment: It will only clear the selected items not to remove the options.